# How I can solve this error in setValues function "The parameters (number[]) don't match the method signature for SpreadsheetApp.Range.setValues"

Tags: javascript, forms, google-apps-script, google-forms

I'm pre-filling a Google form with AppScript, finally I'm saving the urls in an array.

```
var formCol = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getRangeByName('FORM');
var form = FormApp.openByUrl(FORM_URL);
var items = form.getItems();

var urls = [];
for (let i = 1; i < 4; i++ ) {
    
    var formResponse = form.createResponse();

    var formItem = items[0].asTextItem();
    response = formItem.createResponse(botData.id[i]);
    formResponse.withItemResponse(response);

    formItem = items[1].asTextItem();
    response = formItem.createResponse(botData.bot[i]);
    formResponse.withItemResponse(response);

    var date = new Date (botData.date[i].toString());
    var date2 = botData.date[i].toString();
    
    //var day
    formItem = items[3].asTextItem();
    response = formItem.createResponse(botData.zone[i]);
    formResponse.withItemResponse(response);

    formItem = items[8].asTextItem();
    response = formItem.createResponse(botData.remitent[i]);
    formResponse.withItemResponse(response);

    formItem = items[9].asTextItem();
    response = formItem.createResponse(botData.description[i]);
    formResponse.withItemResponse(response);

    formItem = items[11].asTextItem();
    response = formItem.createResponse(botData.solutiontime[i]);
    formResponse.withItemResponse(response);


    var url = formResponse.toPrefilledUrl();
    //sheet.getRange(row, 31).setValue(url);
    url = url.toString()
    urls.push(url)
    
  }
  formCol.setValues(urls);
}
```

I want to print each url in a 'FORM' column of Google Sheets but I get the error "
Exception: The parameters (number[]) don't match the method signature for SpreadsheetApp.Range.setValues." when I try to print the array with setValues, how I can solve this error?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Modification points:

- In your script, `urls` of `formCol.setValues(urls)` is 1 dimensional array. The argument of `setValues(value)` is required to be 2 dimensional array.
- When your range of `var formCol = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getRangeByName('FORM');` is used, the size of the range cannot be known. So, in your situation, it might be required to modify the range for putting the values of `urls`.

When these points are reflected in your script, it becomes as follows.

#### Modified script:

##### From:

```
  urls.push(url)
  
}
formCol.setValues(urls);
```

##### To:

```
  urls.push([url]);
}
formCol.setValues(urls);
```

or

```
  urls.push([url]);
}
formCol.offset(0, 0, urls.length, 1).setValues(urls);
```

#### References:

- [setValues(values)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#setValues(Object))
- [offset(rowOffset, columnOffset, numRows, numColumns)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#offsetrowoffset,-columnoffset,-numrows,-numcolumns)

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are passing an argument that is of the wrong type for the `setValues` function. According to the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#setvaluesvalues), you should pass a two dimensional array.